# How To Create a Plugin at Backend in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a simple contact form plugin and I want it to show on the backend page (wp-admin page).

Comment: you need to create admin pages for this purpose,[https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_object_page](this) link help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use add_menu_page() function for adding new menu in the backend(admin).

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );

}

function my-menu(){
 // Your code ///
}
```